# simple_html_dom example help for a newbie

Tags: php, screen-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to learn the simple_html_dom syntax, but i'm not having much luck.  Could someone show me an example from this:

```
<div id="container">
  <span>Apples</span>
  <span>Oranges</span>
  <span>Bananas</span>
</div>
```

If I want to just return the values Apples, Oranges and Bananas.

Can I simply use the php simple_html_dom class or will I also have to use xcode, curl, etc?

UPDATE:
I was able to get this to work, but not convinced it's the most efficient way of getting what I need:

```
foreach ($html->find('div[id=cont]') as $div);
foreach($div->find('span') as $element) 
echo $element->innertext . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More simply:

```
foreach($html->find('div#container span') as $element)
  echo $element->innerText();
```

That means any span that descends from a div with id: container

Answer (score 2):

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Your suggestion is correct:

```
foreach ($html->find('div[id=cont]') as $div);
foreach($div->find('span') as $element) 
echo $element->innertext . '<br>';
```

Comment: But how do I limit it to items within the container div?